# BITS Compact Server, can this be installed on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: hyper-v, bits

I'm trying to use Microsoft Virtual Machine Converter to connect to an old laptop and create a VM from it, but it needs BITS compact server installed and I can only find how to install this on windows server platforms, not Windows 10. Is this possible, is so how?

(I've attempted to use Disk2VHD on the laptop itself, to a variety of USB 3.0 drives and a network share, but I continually get "semaphore timeout period has expired" so I'm looking for another method of creating a VM)

Answer (score 0):

Disk2VHD is your best bet if you are struggling to run it on the laptop, take the disk out (HDD , SSD, etc) and attached to another computer directly using sata msata, pcie etc. Then RUN Disk2VHD from there, make sure you select all the partitions from that disk. Some times this screws the boot sector, but this can easily be fixed.

There can be multiple different reasons for getting a semaphore timeout period has expired and I am guessing you tired all usual causes.